# How can i run a python script in cronjob without utilising the full server or ec2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python script which is suppose to run every minute, i know how to setup a cron for the same on any server, but that will take a full resource in aws like an ec2 instance, is there any other solution, like lambda? or may be something else on AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html).

Write a Python Lambda function and then direct AWS Lambda to execute it on a regular schedule.